# os.Lstat is failing in a mounted volume on an ubuntu-based Docker container

Tags: docker, go

I have a docker container that uses `go-bindata` to compile a config. I run the docker container with

```
docker run -id \
    -v conf:/conf \
    -e CONF="/conf" \
    my-container
```

Then in the docker container, I install go-bindata, and run

```
RUN go-bindata -prefix $CONF -o $GOPATH/src/github.com/my/repo/dir/conf_generated.go $CW_CONF/config
```

And the output is

```
bindata: Failed to stat input path '/conf/config': lstat /conf/config: no such file or directory
```

[This](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/blob/master/config.go#L165) is the line that is causing the error. It is odd because when I enter the container and run the same command, it works. `stat /conf/config` also works (it knows the file is there). What is going on here? Why doesn't the install line work when the container is building?

Comment: you can always compile the binary outside of the container and COPY it, I prefer this way, your docker images will get very small if you use **alpine** and it saves you from a lot of time and configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the bindata call declared in your Dockerfile. With the RUN prefix it's executed during build of the container when there is no volume yet mounted. If you use the CMD prefix it will run during execution of the container, then the volume is mounted and it should work.

Comment: Good call, that seems obvious now that I'm looking at it. Thanks!